# Use Python Construct to parse 64b *little* endian bitmap into an array of bytes

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, endianness, construct

I need to parse a 64 bit little endian memory into an array of 64 bytes. One bit parses to 1 byte. This will allow me later on to use those bytes for further parsing.
Example: 3B 94 00 00 00 00 00 00
Should be parsed into: 1001010000111011. The 1011 on the right are the LSBs (bits 0-3). Each bit resides in a byte in an array.

The issue I was facing is that I was only able to parse 64b little endian into 64bit single item. Example:
`a = Struct(bmp_struct=BitStruct(bmp=BitsInteger(64, swapped=True)))`
I need to separate the bits as well so I can use them.

On the other hand I was able to parse 64b *big* endian (I need *little* endian) into a 64 byte array. Example:
`a = BitStruct(bmp=Array(64, Byte)`

I was never able to do both. How do I combine the two?

I read a big portion of Python Construct help. It sounds like a simple task however I was not able to pull this off. I am probably missing something since I am a newbie with Construct.

Is there some Python Construct Forum where I post this question?

Thx in advance for anyone trying to take this on!!

YL

Comment: Just parse the source 64 bits from LE to platform local 64 bits (most likely LE anyway), then use standard bit-twiddling to map to a bytes array or a binary? I fail to see where the complexity lies, and have no idea what the code snippets you posted are as they don't look liike anything the standard library provides.

Comment: @Masklinn are you aware this question is about Python Construct library? Are you familiar with Construct? I can parse this without Construct, however this is less cost effective since Construct brings in many advantages.